# Disable selection of a CheckBox in Flex

Tags: checkbox, apache-flex, flex4

I have a checkbox defined as below:

```
<mx:CheckBox id="chkUseAmountDue" change="useAmountDue(event)>
```

What I want is that it should be displayed, but user should not be able to select or deselect the checkbox.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **enabled** attribute inherited from UIComponent:

```
<mx:CheckBox id="chkUseAmountDue" change="useAmountDue(event)" enabled="false">
```

Typically, instead of 'false' you could use a boolean variable that depends on the state of the app.